# Using rand() in recursive function with linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers, recursion, random

When I run the code, the `rand()` function seems to generate the same non-random numbers (my intention is to generate random numbers in `value`). If instead of `rand()` I use the formal parameter `length`, it seems that the code works (getting decreased numbers). Where am I doing wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;    
};

struct node *construct(int);

int main(){
    struct node *list = construct( 5 );

    while( list ){
        printf(" %i\n", list->value);
        list = list->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

//It builds a list of "length" items recursively
struct node *construct(int length){
    struct node *node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    srand(time(NULL));

    node->value = rand(); /* unclear part of code */

    if( length - 1){
        node->next = construct( length - 1 );
    }

    return node;
}
/* missing the code to free memory */

/* example of output */
837240329
837240329
837240329
837240329
837240329
```

Comment: How about reading the documentation of `rand`?

Comment: "The same random numbers" as *what*?  Do you get the same number for each node?  The same number sequence on each execution?  You're posting doesn't have the requested output.

Comment: Call `srand(time(NULL));` *once* at the start of `main`.

Comment: @Olaf: You're right. I had to read better the rand() documentation.
Prune: Yes, the same non-random numbers for each node. I've added an example of output code.
WeatherVane: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

The `srand()` function takes a seed and initializes the *pseudo-random* number generator.

A pseudo-random number generator is not random. Instead, it generates a very-much fixed sequence of numbers that is determined by the seed. A different seed will produce a different sequence, but the same seed, even years later, will produce the same sequence. (This is a feature - it lets you debug programs where the behavior is "random".)

In your case, you are seeding the random number generator each time you call your `construct` function. This is wrong. You should seed the RNG one time, in your `main()` function.

As it stands, your construct function is going to run quickly. And your seed is based on `time()`. So you are very likely to get the same result over and over again, since your function finishes so quickly.

(Kind of like how, when you're sitting in a meeting waiting for it to be over, you keep checking the clock - and it's always the same time...)

Anyway, you call srand(X) (whatever X is) and then a very few instructions later you call srand(X) again. So you're getting the same sequence of random numbers **and only using the first one!**

If you called `srand()` from main, it would be okay. If you *didn't call srand() at all* it would be okay. But as it is, you're always going to get 
srand(X)[0] as the random number in your construct function.